How to get all attributes of an Python object `pxr.Usd.Prim` bound by an C++ object
I am using the Python package pxr to read a USD file. The problem is that I cannot find enough information to fully understand how to work with the objects defined in pxr.
Example code
I am trying to crack a Python object pxr.Usd.Prim which is a binding of a C++ object UsdPrim. The problem is that I cannot get all attributes of the Python object.
usdc_file = "./input/20240506_145520.usdc"
stage = pxr.Usd.Stage.Open(usdc_file)

The stage has the type <class 'pxr.Usd.Stage'>. I can traverse stage as follows:
for prim in stage.Traverse():
    print("prim", type(prim), prim)

The result is
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Geom>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Geom/MDL_OBJ_material0000>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Materials>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Materials/material0000>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Materials/material0000/surfaceShader>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Materials/material0000/st_texCoordReader>)
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520/Materials/material0000/diffuseColor_texture>)

As observed, all primitives in stage have type <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'>.
Try to read attributes
I tried using dir() and vars() to get all attributes by following this question. But only methods are returned. E.g.,
for prim in stage.Traverse():
    def dump(obj):
        for attr in dir(obj):
            print("obj.%s = %r" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
            
    print("prim:", type(prim), prim)
    dump(prim)
    break

The result is
prim: <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'> Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)
obj.AddAppliedSchema = <bound method AddAppliedSchema of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ApplyAPI = <bound method ApplyAPI of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.CanApplyAPI = <bound method CanApplyAPI of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearActive = <bound method ClearActive of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearAssetInfo = <bound method ClearAssetInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearAssetInfoByKey = <bound method ClearAssetInfoByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearChildrenReorder = <bound method ClearChildrenReorder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearCustomData = <bound method ClearCustomData of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearCustomDataByKey = <bound method ClearCustomDataByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearDisplayName = <bound method ClearDisplayName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearDocumentation = <bound method ClearDocumentation of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearHidden = <bound method ClearHidden of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearInstanceable = <bound method ClearInstanceable of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearMetadata = <bound method ClearMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearMetadataByDictKey = <bound method ClearMetadataByDictKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearPayload = <bound method ClearPayload of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearPropertyOrder = <bound method ClearPropertyOrder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ClearTypeName = <bound method ClearTypeName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.ComputeExpandedPrimIndex = <bound method ComputeExpandedPrimIndex of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.CreateAttribute = <bound method CreateAttribute of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.CreateRelationship = <bound method CreateRelationship of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.FindAllAttributeConnectionPaths = <bound method FindAllAttributeConnectionPaths of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.FindAllRelationshipTargetPaths = <bound method FindAllRelationshipTargetPaths of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAllAuthoredMetadata = <bound method GetAllAuthoredMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAllChildren = <bound method GetAllChildren of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAllChildrenNames = <bound method GetAllChildrenNames of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAllMetadata = <bound method GetAllMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAppliedSchemas = <bound method GetAppliedSchemas of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAssetInfo = <bound method GetAssetInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAssetInfoByKey = <bound method GetAssetInfoByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAttribute = <bound method GetAttribute of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAttributeAtPath = <bound method GetAttributeAtPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAttributes = <bound method GetAttributes of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAuthoredAttributes = <bound method GetAuthoredAttributes of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAuthoredProperties = <bound method GetAuthoredProperties of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAuthoredPropertiesInNamespace = <bound method GetAuthoredPropertiesInNamespace of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAuthoredPropertyNames = <bound method GetAuthoredPropertyNames of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetAuthoredRelationships = <bound method GetAuthoredRelationships of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetChild = <bound method GetChild of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetChildren = <bound method GetChildren of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetChildrenNames = <bound method GetChildrenNames of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetChildrenReorder = <bound method GetChildrenReorder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetCustomData = <bound method GetCustomData of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetCustomDataByKey = <bound method GetCustomDataByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetDescription = <bound method GetDescription of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetDisplayName = <bound method GetDisplayName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetDocumentation = <bound method GetDocumentation of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetFilteredChildren = <bound method GetFilteredChildren of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetFilteredChildrenNames = <bound method GetFilteredChildrenNames of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetFilteredNextSibling = <bound method GetFilteredNextSibling of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetInherits = <bound method GetInherits of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetInstances = <bound method GetInstances of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetKind = <bound method GetKind of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetMetadata = <bound method GetMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetMetadataByDictKey = <bound method GetMetadataByDictKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetName = <bound method GetName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetNamespaceDelimiter = <Boost.Python.function object at 0x64c26e21cde0>
obj.GetNextSibling = <bound method GetNextSibling of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetObjectAtPath = <bound method GetObjectAtPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetParent = <bound method GetParent of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPath = <bound method GetPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPayloads = <bound method GetPayloads of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrim = <bound method GetPrim of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimAtPath = <bound method GetPrimAtPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimDefinition = <bound method GetPrimDefinition of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimInPrototype = <bound method GetPrimInPrototype of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimIndex = <bound method GetPrimIndex of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimPath = <bound method GetPrimPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimStack = <bound method GetPrimStack of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimStackWithLayerOffsets = <bound method GetPrimStackWithLayerOffsets of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrimTypeInfo = <bound method GetPrimTypeInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetProperties = <bound method GetProperties of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPropertiesInNamespace = <bound method GetPropertiesInNamespace of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetProperty = <bound method GetProperty of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPropertyAtPath = <bound method GetPropertyAtPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPropertyNames = <bound method GetPropertyNames of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPropertyOrder = <bound method GetPropertyOrder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetPrototype = <bound method GetPrototype of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetReferences = <bound method GetReferences of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetRelationship = <bound method GetRelationship of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetRelationshipAtPath = <bound method GetRelationshipAtPath of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetRelationships = <bound method GetRelationships of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetSpecializes = <bound method GetSpecializes of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetSpecifier = <bound method GetSpecifier of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetStage = <bound method GetStage of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetTypeName = <bound method GetTypeName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetVariantSet = <bound method GetVariantSet of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetVariantSets = <bound method GetVariantSets of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetVersionIfHasAPIInFamily = <bound method GetVersionIfHasAPIInFamily of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.GetVersionIfIsInFamily = <bound method GetVersionIfIsInFamily of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAPI = <bound method HasAPI of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAPIInFamily = <bound method HasAPIInFamily of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAssetInfo = <bound method HasAssetInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAssetInfoKey = <bound method HasAssetInfoKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAttribute = <bound method HasAttribute of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredActive = <bound method HasAuthoredActive of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredAssetInfo = <bound method HasAuthoredAssetInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredAssetInfoKey = <bound method HasAuthoredAssetInfoKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredCustomData = <bound method HasAuthoredCustomData of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredCustomDataKey = <bound method HasAuthoredCustomDataKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredDisplayName = <bound method HasAuthoredDisplayName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredDocumentation = <bound method HasAuthoredDocumentation of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredHidden = <bound method HasAuthoredHidden of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredInherits = <bound method HasAuthoredInherits of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredInstanceable = <bound method HasAuthoredInstanceable of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredMetadata = <bound method HasAuthoredMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredMetadataDictKey = <bound method HasAuthoredMetadataDictKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredPayloads = <bound method HasAuthoredPayloads of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredReferences = <bound method HasAuthoredReferences of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredSpecializes = <bound method HasAuthoredSpecializes of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasAuthoredTypeName = <bound method HasAuthoredTypeName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasCustomData = <bound method HasCustomData of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasCustomDataKey = <bound method HasCustomDataKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasDefiningSpecifier = <bound method HasDefiningSpecifier of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasMetadata = <bound method HasMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasMetadataDictKey = <bound method HasMetadataDictKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasPayload = <bound method HasPayload of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasProperty = <bound method HasProperty of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasRelationship = <bound method HasRelationship of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.HasVariantSets = <bound method HasVariantSets of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsA = <bound method IsA of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsAbstract = <bound method IsAbstract of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsActive = <bound method IsActive of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsComponent = <bound method IsComponent of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsDefined = <bound method IsDefined of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsGroup = <bound method IsGroup of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsHidden = <bound method IsHidden of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsInFamily = <bound method IsInFamily of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsInPrototype = <bound method IsInPrototype of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsInstance = <bound method IsInstance of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsInstanceProxy = <bound method IsInstanceProxy of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsInstanceable = <bound method IsInstanceable of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsLoaded = <bound method IsLoaded of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsModel = <bound method IsModel of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsPathInPrototype = <Boost.Python.function object at 0x64c26e22b350>
obj.IsPrototype = <bound method IsPrototype of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsPrototypePath = <Boost.Python.function object at 0x64c26e22b230>
obj.IsPseudoRoot = <bound method IsPseudoRoot of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsSubComponent = <bound method IsSubComponent of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.IsValid = <bound method IsValid of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.Load = <bound method Load of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.MakeResolveTargetStrongerThanEditTarget = <bound method MakeResolveTargetStrongerThanEditTarget of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.MakeResolveTargetUpToEditTarget = <bound method MakeResolveTargetUpToEditTarget of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.RemoveAPI = <bound method RemoveAPI of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.RemoveAppliedSchema = <bound method RemoveAppliedSchema of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.RemoveProperty = <bound method RemoveProperty of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetActive = <bound method SetActive of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetAssetInfo = <bound method SetAssetInfo of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetAssetInfoByKey = <bound method SetAssetInfoByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetChildrenReorder = <bound method SetChildrenReorder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetCustomData = <bound method SetCustomData of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetCustomDataByKey = <bound method SetCustomDataByKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetDisplayName = <bound method SetDisplayName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetDocumentation = <bound method SetDocumentation of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetHidden = <bound method SetHidden of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetInstanceable = <bound method SetInstanceable of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetKind = <bound method SetKind of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetMetadata = <bound method SetMetadata of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetMetadataByDictKey = <bound method SetMetadataByDictKey of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetPayload = <bound method SetPayload of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetPropertyOrder = <bound method SetPropertyOrder of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetSpecifier = <bound method SetSpecifier of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.SetTypeName = <bound method SetTypeName of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.Unload = <bound method Unload of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj._GetSourcePrimIndex = <bound method _GetSourcePrimIndex of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__bool__ = <bound method __bool__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__class__ = <class 'pxr.Usd.Prim'>
obj.__delattr__ = <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__dict__ = {}
obj.__dir__ = <built-in method __dir__ of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__doc__ = None
obj.__eq__ = <bound method __eq__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__format__ = <built-in method __format__ of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__ge__ = <method-wrapper '__ge__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__getattribute__ = <bound method __getattribute__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__gt__ = <method-wrapper '__gt__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__hash__ = <bound method __hash__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__init__ = <bound method __init__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__init_subclass__ = <built-in method __init_subclass__ of Boost.Python.class object at 0x64c26e1e0390>
obj.__instance_size__ = 56
obj.__le__ = <method-wrapper '__le__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__lt__ = <method-wrapper '__lt__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__module__ = 'pxr.Usd'
obj.__ne__ = <bound method __ne__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__new__ = <built-in method __new__ of Boost.Python.class object at 0x787b44086040>
obj.__reduce__ = <bound method <unnamed Boost.Python function> of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__reduce_ex__ = <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__repr__ = <bound method __repr__ of Usd.Prim(</_20240506_145520>)>
obj.__setattr__ = <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__sizeof__ = <built-in method __sizeof__ of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__str__ = <method-wrapper '__str__' of Prim object at 0x787b16fcd7c0>
obj.__subclasshook__ = <built-in method __subclasshook__ of Boost.Python.class object at 0x64c26e1e0390>
obj.__weakref__ = None

As you can see, it only returns methods.
Getting points attributes by using GetAttribute() and Get()
I found some old code that can get the points information from pxr.UsdGeom.Mesh as follows:
for prim in stage.Traverse():
    if prim.IsA(pxr.UsdGeom.Mesh):
        points = prim.GetAttribute('points').Get()
        print(f"points: {type(points)}")
        points = np.array(points)
        print(f"points: {points.shape}")

It first checks if prim is pxr.UsdGeom.Mesh. If so, it uses prim.GetAttribute('points').Get() to get the points from the mesh and turn it into a Numpy array. The output is:
points: <class 'pxr.Vt.Vec3fArray'>
points: (26330, 3)

But how do I know I can use this operation to get the information like this?
My question
Based on the above description, my question is the following:

How do I know I can get what attributes from the pxr.Usd.Prim? I've read through the USD manual and omniverse manual but cannot find any relevant information.


You missed this page which lists attributes for all classes.

You could also go read the USD specification files directly, but it sure looks like there should be documentation generated somewhere, too.
